# Set Faraday Timeout in Ruby ElasticSearch Client

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, faraday

Is it possible to set the `timeout` property of a Faraday transport when creating a Ruby `Elasticsearch::Client`? There is the scope to pass a block when initializing an `Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Faraday` instance, but when trying the below we only ever get an empty set of connections back from `__build_connections`:

```
transport = Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Faraday.new do |connection|
  # connection.timeout = 1 # ???
end
```

Any suggestions as to how we should implement this block to set the timeout?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can run this.

```
Elasticsearch::Client.new transport_options: {
  request: { timeout: 1 }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! So nice when I google and a workable, concise answer pops up  :)

Comment: Is the value in seconds or ms?